Ability of Integrate[ ] to try changes of variable on its own
I have a question about Mathematica's ability to try changes of variable when performing symbolic integration. My example is
$$ \int_0^\infty dx\ x^n \exp \left( -h \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} \right) = \frac{2^{n/2} a^{1 + n} (a h)^{-n/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}
  K_{(2 + n)/2}(a h)\ \Gamma((1 + n)/2). $$
When I try this integral in Mathematica 10.0 for Windows, it is returned unchanged. However, if I make the obvious change of variable, as
Integrate[ ((x^n Exp[-h Sqrt[x^2 + a^2] ] /. x -> Sqrt[u^2 - a^2])                     
         * D[Sqrt[u^2 - a^2], u]) // PowerExpand, {u, a, \[Infinity]}]

I get
ConditionalExpression[(2^(n/2) a^(1 + n) (a h)^(-n/2) BesselK[(2 + n)/2, a h] Gamma[(1 + n)/2])/Sqrt[\[Pi]], 
 Re[h] > 0 && Re[n] > -1 && Re[a] > 0 && Im[a] == 0]

I have found this behavior in versions up to 14. Why does Mathematica not try this (simple) substitution?
(I also tried MellinTransform[ ], and it also fails to return a result.)
Thanks,
Tom

Unless the change of variable is builtin and known one for some typical integrands, it will be hard on the fly to make Integrate try all possible change of variables. right? That is why there is separate command IntegrateChangeVariables to allow users to do their own change of variable. May be in the future when AI and chatGPT start to do all the math for us, then AI will be able to do this.

@Nasser - Thanks, COV does seem too hard for a symbolic programming language but just about right for AI, which I'm sure Wolfram will add at some point.
